# Windows 10 broken after install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

So I was with just windows 10 installed and I installed Ubuntu 16 here and now I can't boot windows 10
here's my paste boot info: http://paste2.org/gMBhJyMp

If I check the windows partition with gParted it is with an red warning that says:

```
Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x36892, last_vcn - 1 = 0x5d57f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Input/output error
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
made to NTFS by this software.

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

But I can't access windows, so I can't write the command **chkdsk /f**

I already tried to use boot repair logged in ubuntu, and It not worked
any ideas?

Comment: It's giving an input/output error on the Windows partition, which either means it needs `chkdsk /f` do be run or the drive is failing/has a loose connection. Open the `Disks` program on Ubuntu and check the health of the drive. Also check the drive's physical connection to the computer. In what way does Windows not boot: what's the error?

Comment: so thi is my SSD 120GB, the health is very good, ubuntu is running on it now, windows doesn't boot I just select windows option at grub, try to load it and my pc restart

Comment: Ah, OK. So, I think you have to download a Windows ISO and burn it to a USB or Disc. Boot from that, start the setup, go to "Repair Computer" (something like that. It's a link on the bottom left), and let it try Startup Repair. If that doesn't work, go to the advanced options and choose CMD. Run the chkdsk on C:.

Comment: cool, you know if windows 7 ISO will fix it, or I need to get an windows 10 ISO?

Comment: If it's WIndows 10, get a Windows 10 ISO.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as if you have installed GRUB into the boot partition. 

 Anyway each system installation overwrites the MBR so previous installations (mostly Windows) cannot boot. Since Win2k Windows needs to boot with the BCD or it can't find itself. 

Stupid? – Yes … 

As **wtkd** said, you will need to **repair the MBR** with an original installation disc, which then overwrtes the MBR again for booting into BCD.

After that you will not be able to boot into Linux.

But you'll have two options:

- fix the MBR for Windows 
   install a BCD editor 
   try to add a Linux boot option (*this is really complicated but not impossible*) 
  – if GRUB is on the system volume, you'll have to select this volume
  – if not, see next option:
- *boot into Linux* 
   install GRUB again but this time install GRUB into the (Linux) system volume 
   Nevertheless the MBR will be overwritten again, so you will have to fix Windows again as described.

If you have a second HDD you can use a workaround for this problem:

1. Leave the Windows boot volume untouched (*after repair!*).
2. Install GRUB to the second HDD's boot (=active) partition. 
    This partition can be tiny (~50-100MB) and anywhere on the HDD as long as it is marked "**active**". But for faster booting it should be near the beginning of the disk.
3. Go to your BIOS and change the boot disk option to that second HDD.
4. Update GRUB. 
    That way it will add Windows (*actually the BCD*) to its menu and if selected it just switches back to the first HDD's boot volume, where BCD will be loaded.

The trouble herein is that you cannot edit the BCD unless BIOS boots from this HDD. Thou – if you can manage to add a boot entry in BCD for Linux – you are free to decide from which HDD to boot. Howsoever it is not to avoid to have to boot through two boot managers.

So changing something here can really make you nuts. ;-)